# Why is this.props.navigate() not working? The console.log error says that invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am new to reactJS. I am trying to navigate to the specific room/roomcode page which I know exists. I have gone to the room/roomcode page to manually verify this. What I was wondering is how to use this hook in this class, or if I can not use it what would be the way around this error?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextField, Button, Grid, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class RoomJoinPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      roomCode: "",
      error: "",
    };
    this.handleTextFieldChange = this.handleTextFieldChange.bind(this);
    this.roomButtonPressed = this.roomButtonPressed.bind(this);
  }

  handleTextFieldChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      roomCode: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  roomButtonPressed() {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code: this.state.roomCode,
      }),
    };

    fetch("/api/join-room", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          this.props.navigate("/room/" + this.state.roomCode);
        } else {
          this.setState({ error: "Room not found." });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

This is my Homepage.js which is directly called by App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RoomJoinPage from "./RoomJoinPage";
import CreateRoomPage from "./CreateRoomPage";
import Room from "./Room";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  } from "react-router-dom";

  export default class HomePage extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
  }

render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<p>This is the home page</p>} />
      <Route path="/join" element={<RoomJoinPage />} />
      <Route path="/create" element={<CreateRoomPage />} />
      <Route path="/room/:roomCode" element={<Room />} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is this `navigate` prop coming from? Are you using a React hook somewhere? Can you include all relevant code in your post? See [mcve].

Comment: I thought that navigate was a react inbuilt function. It worked in another file of mine.

Comment: It's not a built-in React function. What is the other file you are referencing where it's working?

Comment: Here, added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the `HomePage` component is using the `useNavigate` hook or calling any `navigate` function.

In `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer any "route props" like there were in RRDv5, `location`, `navigate`, etc. are now all accessed via React hooks.

If you need to us the `navigate` function in a class component you'll need to create your own component that can use the `useNavigate` hook and pass `navigate` as a prop to class component.

Example Higher Order Component:

```
import { useNavigate, /* other hooks */ } from 'react-router-dom'; 

const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // other hooks

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      {...{ navigate, /* other hooks */ }}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter;
```

...

```
...
import withRouter from '../path/to/withRouter';

export default class RoomJoinPage extends Component {
  state = {
    roomCode: "",
    error: "",
  }

  handleTextFieldChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      roomCode: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  roomButtonPressed = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code: this.state.roomCode,
      }),
    };

    fetch("/api/join-room", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          this.props.navigate("/room/" + this.state.roomCode);
        } else {
          this.setState({ error: "Room not found." });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  ...

  render() { .... }
}

export default withRouter(RoomJoinPage);
```

...

```
<Route path="/join" element={<RoomJoinPage />} />
```